# Multiple flow layout panels panel.Focus() not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I've made a program with a flow layout panel and multiple dynamically-generated layout panels inside of that panel.

Now I want to scroll through the sub-panels when the mouse hovers over them, but just setting `panel.Focus();` to a panel doesn't work. I need to click in the panel, but the panel is completely filled with clickable items. So I want to make it focus if I just hover.

Any ideas why panel.Focus() doesn't work, or do you know what could cause this issue?

Comment: A panel doesn't *want* the focus, it has no use for it.  It can't indicate focus and doesn't handle keyboard input.  So it passes it immediately to one if its children.  It is otherwise very unclear how you intend to scroll by clicking the mouse.  Click on the scrollbar instead or use the mouse wheel.  If you don't have a scrollbar then you forgot to set the AutoScroll property to True.

Comment: ive got a scrollbar, just want to set the current panel to be scrolled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope Hans' forgives me, but [his code example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eb922ed2-1036-41ca-bd15-49daed7b637c/outlookstyle-wheel-mouse-behavior?forum=winforms) does what you want by implementing an IMessageFilter interface to listen to the wheel message and forwards it to the scrollable control the mouse is currently over.  No need to use `Panel1.Focus();`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pt);
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
  }

  public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x20a) {
      Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
      IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pos);
      if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero && hWnd != m.HWnd && Control.FromHandle(hWnd) != null) {
        SendMessage(hWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```